# Building ANTLR4 source to get source jar

Tags: intellij-idea, jar, antlr, antlr4

I could download the newest ANTLR4 (antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar) from the download page (http://www.antlr.org/download.html).

Putting the jar file in the lib directory of IntelliJ project to make the jar as a dependency to see everything works fine.

I'm trying to look into the ANTLR's source code by tracing with debugger, but I can't as I don't have the source jar.

I found the source code, and an instruction to build ANTLR (
[How to build ANTLR itself](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/wiki/How-to-build-ANTLR-itself)). However, the instruction uses `bild.py` that is not included in the source.

I found the bild.py from Sam Hawell's [tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/blob/master/bild.py), but when I copy the script and run it, I got errors:

```
target all
require compile
require parsers
build compile
skipping mkjar_complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/smcho/Downloads/antlr4-4.5.3/bilder.py", line 847, in processargs
    target()
  File "bild.py", line 182, in all
    mkjar()
  File "bild.py", line 133, in mkjar
    mkjar_complete()
  File "bild.py", line 80, in mkjar_complete
    require(compile)
  File "/Users/smcho/Downloads/antlr4-4.5.3/bilder.py", line 434, in require
    raise Exception()
Exception
bild failed
```

What might be wrong? How to build ANTLR4 to get source jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get source (and/or javadoc), you should simply use ivy. You could also use maven as you wrote, but ivy is simpler IMHO. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4/4.5.3

Comment: Runtime should be added: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.5.3

Comment: Either eay, but when triggering ivy just say thay you want src and doc

Comment: I use sbt, and with sbt source jar is also installed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`maven` is the tool to build the jar files as is described in this document: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/building-antlr.md

`mvn compile` gets the compilation done.

For getting the source jar file, pom.xml should be updated.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

Then `mvn package` will make the source jar in `tool/target` directory.

[image]

For the runtime jar, the target directory is `runtime/Java/target`.

[image]

`mvn install` will install the jars into local repository.

#### References

- [Generate source code jar for Maven based project](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/generate-source-code-jar-for-maven-based-project/)